# Add a zero to all entries that match my filter (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have this to find all the rows where I have a problem:

```
select * from `full_local_demographic` where length(fips) < 5
```

These find all the rows where `fips` are less than 5 characters. These should all be 5 characters. When they were uploaded, the data was incorrect and dropped the leading zero. What do I need to add to my mysql query in order to add the zero back to the front for all the `fips` entries that are found by the query above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `lpad()`

```
select lpad(fips, 5, '0')
from full_local_demographic
```

You don't even need the `where` clause.  If you want to update the values, then a `where` clause is advisable:

```
update full_local_demographic
    set fips = lpad(fips, 5, '0')
    where length(fips) < 5;
```

Comment: I'd like to update them in the table permanently, so do I need the second query?

Comment: The second query does nothing. It affects 0 rows. The first query works, but doesn't update. Not sure what the issue might be.

Comment: Got it working...figured out the problem was that on my table I had `fips` set as an INT. I changed to VARCHAR and it worked fine. Thanks.